# How can I resolve the side effects of AddEverypageHook to external pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

I have quite a huge document with many pgfplots, which I would like to externalize. Well I can externalize them, but my `\AddEverypageHook` command from the `everypage` package affects this externalized plots.

I add a background picture to every page:

```
\AddEverypageHook{\ThisTileWallPaper{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}{res/background.pdf}}
```

Unfortunately this background picture appears in the externalized plots:
[image: error]

Has anyone an idea to resolve this?

## Update

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
    \ThisULCornerWallPaper{}{res/background.pdf}

    \begin{figure}[h!tbp]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                        height=5cm,
                        width=\textwidth,
                        domain=-3:10
                    \addplot[color=black] (x);
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `background.pdf`-file is an `A4` paper. It produces this result:
[image: bla]

Comment: Without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), I think this could be very difficult to diagnose. Could you narrow down your large file to exhibit the issue with a simple `pgfplot` and basic background image from the [`mwe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe) or similar? This would make it more accessible to the community and you might discover the problem yourself in making the MWE. `:-)`

Comment: I would try TikZ and its absolute positioning instead of page hooking. Usually we deal with one resulting picture, then we put whole `tikzpicture` environment into header by using `\fancyhead` command from the `fancyhdr` package.

Comment: Sorry, for the long quiet time! I had to finish the paper first. I've finally added a minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\tikzifexternalizing{<code for true>}{<code for false>}` to make something different during the externalization:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
    \tikzifexternalizing{}{%
    \ThisULCornerWallPaper{}{PP.pdf}%
    }

    \begin{figure}[h!tbp]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                        height=5cm,
                        width=\textwidth,
                        domain=-3:10]
                    \addplot[color=black] {x};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My image is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[left color=red,right color=white] (0,0) rectangle(10,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS
Note the compile errors in your external image.